# Parsing a string read in from a file

Tags: c, parsing

The code below is part of a program that will check movie reviews and see if they are positive reviews or negative reviews. Positive and negative are linked lists that store around 2000 words in each that were loaded earlier. I am trying to read in the review file with these two functions and determine if they are positive or negative. Is this the correct way to try and read in an entire file and then parse it word by word to see if the word is positive or negative. I am seg faulting on the fgets line so I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what.

```
  int check_word(node* positive, node* negative, char* word)
    {
        while(positive->nextPtr != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(positive->word,word) == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                positive = positive->nextPtr;
            }
        }

        while(negative->nextPtr != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(negative->word,word) == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                negative = negative->nextPtr;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
    void evaluate_review(node* positive,node* negative, char* file)
    {
        FILE* fp = fopen(file,"r");
        char* token = NULL;
        char* review = NULL;
        int positive_words = 0;
        int negative_words = 0;

        fgets(review, 300, fp);

        token = strtok(review, " " );
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(check_word(positive, negative, token) == 1)
            {
                positive_words++;
            }
            else if(check_word(positive, negative, token) == -1)
            {
                negative_words++;
            }

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }

        if(positive_words > negative_words)
        {
            printf("This review was a postive one\n");
        }

        if( negative_words > positive_words)
        {
            printf("This review was a negative one\n");
        }

        fclose(fp);



    }
```

Comment: that did the trick, thank you can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson to make the code more maintainable you could `fgets(review, sizeof(review), fp);` then changing the size of the array will not require changing `fgets()`...

Comment: Good point, however if I use the array as size 300 it wouldn't matter anyway correct since I am not dynamically changing the actual size of the array

Comment: Also better to test the return of `fgets` e.g. to read all lines `while (fgets(review, 300, fp) != NULL) { ... do stuff ... }`.

Comment: Well if the input file data is all on the same line it is going to read it all in at once which it is doing in my case, my program works fine now but I see your point

Comment: You have a very good point. No need to read the same line over and aver again. Results never change.... Kind of boring actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(review, 300, fp);
```

writes into an uninitialized memory location. You need to allocate memory for `review`. You have two options to do it:

1. Make `review` point to an array of `char` of size 300 bytes:

   ```
   char* review = NULL;
   char array[300];

   review=array;
   ```
2. Allocate memory dynamically for `review` using `malloc`/`calloc`.

   ```
   char* review = NULL;

   review = malloc(300);
   /*OR*/
   review = calloc(300 , sizeof(char));
   ```

   and then, free it after its use using

   ```
   free(review);
   ```

   It is also a good idea to check if `malloc`/`calloc` did not fail by checking its return value. It will return `NULL` on failure.

It is also a good idea to check if `fgets` doesn't return `NULL`.